# How to calculate rolling bootstrapped values and confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, moving-average, statistics-bootstrap

I am new to R and am trying to calculate the bootstrapped standard deviation (sd) and associated standard error within a 30 observation rolling window. The function below performs the rolling window appropriately if I just want sd. But when I add the bootstrap function using the boot package I get the error specified below. I gather that I am trying to store bootstrap results in a vector that isn't the correct size. Does anyone have any advice on how to store just the bootstrapped sd and associated stderror for each window in rows of a new matrix? The goal is to then plot the sd and associated 95% confidence intervals for each window along the timeseries. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
> head(data.srs)
    LOGFISH
1  0.8274083
2  1.0853433
3  0.8049845
4  0.8912097
5  1.3514569
6  0.8694499


###Function to apply rolling window

rollWin <- function(timeSeries,  windowLength) 
{
  data<-timeSeries
  nOut <- length(data[, 1]) - windowLength + 1
  out <- numeric(nOut)
  if (length(data[,1]) >= windowLength)
  {
    for (i in 1:nOut) 
      { 
      sd.fun <- function(data,d)sd(data[d], na.rm = TRUE)
      out[i] <- boot(data[i:(i + windowLength - 1), ], sd.fun, R=1000)
      }
  }
  return (list(result=out))
} 

###run rolling window function. ex. rollWin(data, windowlength)
a.temp<-rollWin(data.srs,30)


> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In out[i] <- boot(data[i:(i + windowLength - 1), ], sd.fun,  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it quite a lot. I am not familiar with the `boot` package, but we can roll a function along a vector using the `rollapply` function quite easily, and then we can make bootstrap samples using the `replicate` function:

```
# Create some data, 12 items long
r <- runif(12)
# [1] 0.44997964 0.27425412 0.07327872 0.68054759 0.33577348 0.49239478
# [7] 0.93421646 0.19633079 0.45144966 0.53673296 0.71813017 0.85270346


require(zoo)

# use rollapply to calculate function alonga  moving window
# width is the width of the window
sds <- rollapply( r , width = 4 , by = 1 , sd )
#[1] 0.19736258 0.26592331 0.16770025 0.12585750 0.13730946 0.08488467
#[7] 0.16073722 0.22460430 0.22462168


# Now we use replicate to repeatedly evaluate a bootstrap sampling method
# 'n' is number of replications
n <- 4
replicate( n , rollapply( r , width = n , function(x) sd( x[ sample(length(x) , repl = TRUE) ] ) ) )



#            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.17934073 0.1815371 0.11603320 0.2992379
# [2,] 0.03551822 0.2862702 0.18492837 0.2526193
# [3,] 0.09042535 0.2419768 0.13124738 0.1666012
# [4,] 0.17238705 0.1410475 0.18136178 0.2457248
# [5,] 0.32008385 0.1709326 0.32909368 0.2550859
# [6,] 0.30832533 0.1480320 0.02363968 0.1275594
# [7,] 0.23069951 0.1275594 0.25648052 0.3016909
# [8,] 0.11235170 0.2493055 0.26089969 0.3012610
# [9,] 0.16819174 0.2099518 0.18033502 0.0906986
```

Each column represents the rollapply which bootstraps the observations in the current window before applying `sd`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unless I do not understand, it looks like your method resamples from the entire time series, I need to resample within each moving window. So if the first window has the last 30 observations, the bootstrap function is applied only to that window (those 30 observations). Then save the mean bootstrapped sd and the confidence intervals in a row of a new matrix. Then the window slides over 1 observation and repeats until the end of the time series.

Comment: @Gladeslab ok - give me a few minutes to fix that

Comment: @Gladeslab check the edit. It's just a subtle change in the replicate line. Cheers.

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Now I can just calculate the mean of each row and 95% confidence intervals from the matrix this created. Thank you so much for your help.